# gpg: public key decryption failed: Bad passphrase

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, gnupg

I'm trying to decrypt a file using GPG, for which I use "Starksoft.Cryptography.OpenPGP". I'm getting the following error

```
Starksoft.Cryptography.OpenPGP.GnuPGException: An error occurred while trying to execute command --list-secret-keys.
```

But when I execute the command through command prompt ">gpg --list-secret-keys", it does list the keys. I could not get "Starksoft.Cryptography.OpenPGP" to work correctly.

Next I tried to get a solution by running the process directly using cmd.exe. None of the following commands is working however:

```
>echo gpg --passphrase Mypasspharse -o "C:\successtest.txt" -d "C:\testfile.txt.gpg"

>echo Mypasspharse|gpg.exe --passphrase-fd 0 -o "C:\successtest.txt" --decrypt "C:\testfile.txt.gpg"

>echo Mypasspharse|gpg --keyring "pubring.gpg location" --secret-keyring "secring.gpg location" --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 -o "C:\successtest.txt" -d "C:\testfile.txt.gpg"


>echo Mypasspharse|gpg -o C:\successtest.txt --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt C:\testfile.txt.gpg


 >echo Mypasspharse|gpg2 --batch --passphrase-file "PrivateKey.asc location" --output C:\successtest.txt --decrypt C:\testfile.txt.gpg

Error Message : gpg: public key decryption failed: Bad passphrase
                gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Can anybody show me how to decrypt the file?

Comment: Hi Viji, could you check if my changes make sense to you? I had a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: yes. thks for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue with the gpg command line. The second command line worked just fine.

> echo Mypasspharse|gpg.exe --passphrase-fd 0 -o "C:\successtest.txt" --decrypt "C:\testfile.txt.gpg"

Issue Was :

```
 Mypassphare contained a character ">" which interpreted as std out redirect in windows command prompt. So, passphase wasn't passing to the next command properly.
```

Since this command worked properly, I didn't check on other syntax. Please feel free to check other commands and update here, if its wrong.

I have summarized the Q & A here: http://techsharehub.blogspot.com/2014/09/gpg-public-key-decryption-failed-bad.html